# How to set firefox homepage from terminal?

Tags: scripting, configuration, firefox

I am trying to configure firefox from a script. I have already hit a wall establishing the deafault homepage.

Found some old info what does not work anymore: `echo "user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "https://www.google.com");" >> /etc/xul-ext/ubufox.js`

Digging a little, I found the xulrunner directory is now /usr/lib64/xulrunner, but nor there nor in the firefox directory I can found a configuration file.

Does anyone know where is it?

Answer (score 6):

This is stored in the user's `~/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILE_NAME.default/prefs.js` file:

```
$ grep browser.startup.homepage .mozilla/firefox/0prxyjky.default/prefs.js
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://foobar.com");
```

The profile name will be different for all users but should always end with `.default`.

If you want to change this for all new users that will be added, you can edit `/etc/skel/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/prefs.js` which is the template file for new profiles. I am not sure if the `mwad0hks.default` will be the same on all systems, but you should have something with an equivalent name there.

Comment: Just loeked up /etc/skel/.mozilla directory and there is no firefox, only extensions and plugins directorys. Strange, so wgere do I have to look if I want to change all profiles?

Comment: `mwad0hks` is a randomly generated string. You can remove it (the “security” reason for having it is silly). You need to record the profile location in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`. If a directory you need doesn't exist under `/etc/skel`, just create it. @NotFromBrooklyn

Comment: But if the folder is not there, from which file was my profile created?, because I'm using firefox right now.

Comment: But how do I replace the value? Would it be something like `grep browser.startup.homepage ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js | awk '{print $2}' | sed '1 s/\"*www*\"/\"www.google.com\"/'` ?

Comment: @Arturo just open the file on a text editor and make the change. Or do you want to do it to multiple profiles?

Comment: @terdon I'd like to add this to a script.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox may overwrite items in `prefs.js`. You should create a new `user.js` in the same profile directory and put your `user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "https://example.homepage.com");` in there.

This is a very hacky one liner to pull down the `prefs.js` file from a github gist and saves in place, whatever the users default profile is.

```
sudo wget -O `cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default ; pwd`/user.js https://gist.githubusercontent.com/metahertz/c46bd4a62f33616bdc6c0750021a0c77/raw/daddaf6a6809025e969e06a5cda00204af115118/user.js
```